# How can I map array with multiple objects and display on chart?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, recharts

I want to display my data that I collect from firestore database and show it on charts, using Rechart in React.
This is how my data looks like:

[image]

When I want to display everyting on one chart - everything works fine.
But I want to create that many single charts how much objects I have.
I mean, every new trip = new chart.

This is how my code looks like right now.

Saving data into array

```js
const getData = async () => {
    const data = [];

    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(
      collection(databaseRef, `${cUser}/userinfo/trips`)
    );
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data().Title);
      data.push({
        Trip: doc.data().Trip,
        Distance: doc.data().Distance,
        Time: doc.data().Time,
        Calories: doc.data().Calories,
      });
    });
    setData(data);
    console.log(data);
  };
```

This code generate 2 different charts, what is OK but without any data.

```js
 {dataToShow.map((item) => {
        return (
          <>
            <BarChart width={600} height={600} data={item}>
              <XAxis dataKey={item.Trip} />
              <YAxis dataKey={item.Distance} />

              <Bar dataKey={item.Calories} barSize={30} fill="#8884d8" />
              <Bar dataKey={item.Time} barSize={30} fill="#fcba03" />
            </BarChart>
          </>
        );
      })}
```

What's wrong with my mapping?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

To display your different `Bar` elements, you don't need to loop into every item of your array.

Instead, you just need to use the prop `dataKey` per Bar, where you specify the data you want to use as a string, just like the following:

```
// {dataToShow.map((item) => { <-- remove this
return (
  <BarChart width={600} height={600} data={dataToShow}> // update the `data` prop with your data array
    <XAxis dataKey="Trip" />
    <YAxis dataKey="Distance" />

    <Bar dataKey="Calories" barSize={30} fill="#8884d8" />
    <Bar dataKey="Time" barSize={30} fill="#fcba03" />
  </BarChart>
);
// })} <-- to remove
```

Recharts will understand the data you're pointing to with the same prop name ("Trip", and so on).

Comment: Hi!
I know that I do not need to loop after every item of my array.
But it works fine untill I want to display data on 1 chart.
But for every single object from my array I want to render chart only with specific data from this array!
Thanks for any advice

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want to have one chart per item then?

Comment: Yes. One chart per object in array (Trip, Distance, Calories, Time)

Comment: Problem resolved